# MS Access 2013 - How do I select unique values from another table?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a database with three tables; `tbl_Room`, `tbl_Guest` and `tbl_RoomGuest` (a bit simplified).

```
`tbl_Room` has information about a certain room
`tbl_Guest` has information about a certain guest
`tbl_RoomGuest` has information about what guest stayed at which room,
and the dates they stayed.
```

I am making a form where I can enter information about a room, and I want to display a list of the guests that have stayed in that room.

How can I select the names from `tbl_Guest`, when I want to display unique names of only the guests that stayed in that room?

I want the field to be non-editable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query to get the unique names could be written using `distinct`.  Here is an example:

```
select distinct g.GuestName
from tbl_RoomGuest as rg inner join
     tbl_Guest g
     on rg.GuestId = rg.GuestId
where rg.RoomId = YOURROOMIDHERE;
```